# Cone's lateral surface area differential

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I represent half of a 2d projection of a cone onto an $xy$-plane by $f(x)=(\frac RH)x$.

[image]

When I was first trying to find it, my natural instinct was to consider a constant radius over a small distance, so that $ds=2\pi\left[(\frac RH)x\right]dx$, but, of course, this turned out to be wrong.

After some digging, I found someone who took it as $ds=2\pi\left[(\frac RH)x\right]dl$, where $dl$ is an element of the lateral distance $l=\sqrt{(\frac RH)^2x^2+x^2}$.

Is there an explanation to why we should expect the second form to work and the first to fail?

Comment: 2d projection onto *WHAT*?

Comment: a plane. @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Duh... but *WHAT* plane?  it makes *all* the difference!!!!!   One perpendicular to the axis of the cone????  One *parallel* to the axis of the cone???  One at an odd angle?  Draw a picture!!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have the right idea. You need to consider thin circular strips along the lateral surface area of the cone. The area of one of these thin circular strips is found by multiplying the circumference of the strip by the width of the strip.

The circumference is something you found: $2\pi \left( \frac{R}{H} \right) x$.

For the width, we are debating whether to use $dx$ (a differential measured along the x-axis) or $dl$ (a differential measured along the lateral surface of the cone.

The correct choice is $dl$, since the true width of the circular strip is measured along the lateral surface. On the other hand, $dx$ would be measuring the width of the *projection* of the strip onto the $x$-axis. Therefore, $dx$ does not measure the true width of the strip.

Consider a scenario where you travel from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(1,1)$. To measure the distance you traveled, you need to measure it in the direction in which you are moving. If instead, you measured it along the $x$-axis (from $x = 0$, to $x = 1$), you would compute a distance of $1$ which is incorrect.

The same idea applies to the cone. The circular strip is on the lateral surface, so its width needs to be measured along the lateral surface.

(For reference, the cone we are considering is $y^2 + z^2 = \left(\frac{R}{H}x\right)^2, 0\leq x\leq H$).